# Add 0 or 1 in a df depending on conditions from another df

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe `df1` with:

```
file_name  loc
rep1   chr1:62161618:62162663:-
rep2   chr1:62161618:62162669:-
...
```

And I generate an empty matrix (`df2`) with `file_name` as rows and `loc` as columns. I want to add "1" value in every position that is present in `df1`. As an example:

```
     chr1:62161618:62162663:-    chr1:62161618:62162669:-...
rep1           1                            0
rep2           0                            1
...
```

Any suggestions? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A solution using `dplyr` and `tidyr`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dt2 <- dt %>%
  mutate(condition = 1) %>%
  spread(loc, condition, fill = 0)
dt2
#   file_name chr1:62161618:62162663:- chr1:62161618:62162669:-
# 1      rep1                        1                        0
# 2      rep2                        0                        1
```

**DATA**

```
dt <- read.table(text = "file_name  loc
rep1   'chr1:62161618:62162663:-'
                 rep2   'chr1:62161618:62162669:-'",
                 header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the feedback! 
I was wondering if the code would be different if, instead of 0 and 1 I would use a third column with values in the `df1` to fill the `df2`.

Comment: I think you may need a join operation for that. You may want to ask a new question.