# Create a "continuous" matrix operator

Tags: r

Following this previous question:
[Add 0 or 1 in a df depending on conditions from another df](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47330309/add-0-or-1-in-a-df-depending-on-conditions-from-another-df)

I have now a similar purpose but a bit different. I have `df1` but with a third column "value":

```
file_name  loc                        num
rep1       chr1:62161618:62162663:-   3
rep2       chr1:62161618:62162669:-   5
...
```

I would like to generate a `df2` matrix with `file_name` as rows and `loc` as columns. Finally I want to fill the matrix `df2` with the values from `num` and 0 for the rest, something like:

```
     chr1:62161618:62162663:-    chr1:62161618:62162669:-...
rep1           3                            0
rep2           0                            5
...
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `tidyr`'s `spread`:

```
df <- data.frame(file_name = c("rep1", "rep2"), 
           loc = c("chr1:62161618:62162663:-", "chr1:62161618:62162669:-"),
           num = c(3,5))

library(tidyr)
df <- spread(df, key = loc, value = num, fill = 0)
row.names(df) <- df$file_name
df <- df[,-1]

     chr1:62161618:62162663:- chr1:62161618:62162669:-
rep1                        3                        0
rep2                        0                        5
```

Comment: You can use spread(loc, num, fill = 0) to fill NAs with 0